# 2 listagg in one SQL Select in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have a table in the form of :

```
| ID    | COURSE | PASS |
---------------------------
| 1     | 1      | 1      |
| 1     | 2      | 1      |    
| 1     | 3      | 1      |
| 1     | 4      | 0      |
| 1     | 5      | 0      |
```

and I want row in the form:

```
| ID    | FAILED | PASSED |
---------------------------
| 1     | 4,5    | 1,2,3  |
```

the only i figured is something like this:

```
    select NVL(passed.id, failed.id), passed.test, failed.test from 
        (select id, listagg(course, ',') within group (order by course) test from table1 where pass = 1 group by id ) passed 
    full outer join
        (select id, listagg(course, ',') within group (order by course) test from table1 where pass = 0 group by id ) failed
    on passed.id = failed.id
```

is there a way to do it in a single query ?

Comment: What DB engine are you using?

Comment: `listagg ... within group` suggests Oracle

Comment: Oracle... edited the q.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try

```
select  id, 
  listagg(case when pass = 1 then course end, ',') within group (order by course) passed,
  listagg(case when pass = 0 then course end, ',') within group (order by course) failed
from table1
group by id
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/426a0/11)